# Cómo utilizar SUM() y GROUP BY() directamente en dataset and query de JASPERSOFT 6.12.2 o posible solución con variables

Tags: sql, jasper-reports

Mi pregunta es cómo puedo utilizar el método SUM() y GROUP BY() directamente en el dataset de Jaspersoft.
Quiero obtener la suma de los valores que se encuentran en las filas de una columna, agrupando por el código de una tabla. Debo aclarar que el GROUP BY() lo puedo realizar directamente, pero el SUM() no, es decir que me agrupa, pero no teniendo en cuenta la suma de la columna.

```
SELECT presupuesto.presupuesto.`idPresupuesto`,
    presupuesto.presupuesto.`Presupuesto_Proyecto`,
    presupuesto.cantidades_obra.`Cantidades_Obra_Cantidad`,
    presupuesto.recurso.`RecursoNombre`,
    presupuesto.medida.`MedidaAbreviacion` AS medida,
    presupuesto.recurso.`RecursoValorUnitario`,
    presupuesto.detalle_apu.`Recurso_RecursoCodigo`,
    presupuesto.detalle_apu.`Detalle_APU_Cantidad`,
    presupuesto.recurso.`RecursoCategoria`
FROM presupuesto.presupuesto
    INNER JOIN presupuesto.cantidades_obra ON 
     presupuesto.cantidades_obra.`id_Presupuesto` = presupuesto.presupuesto.`idPresupuesto` 
    INNER JOIN presupuesto.apu ON 
     presupuesto.apu.`APU_Codigo` = presupuesto.cantidades_obra.`Cantidades_CodigoAPU` 
    INNER JOIN presupuesto.detalle_apu ON 
     presupuesto.detalle_apu.`Detalle_CodigoAPU` = presupuesto.apu.`APU_Codigo` 
    INNER JOIN presupuesto.recurso ON 
     presupuesto.recurso.`Recurso_Codigo` = presupuesto.detalle_apu.`Recurso_RecursoCodigo` 
    INNER JOIN presupuesto.medida ON 
     presupuesto.medida.`idMedida` = presupuesto.recurso.`Medida_idMedida` 
WHERE 
     presupuesto.presupuesto.`idPresupuesto` = '1' 
     GROUP BY presupuesto.detalle_apu.`Recurso_RecursoCodigo`
ORDER BY presupuesto.recurso.`RecursoCategoria` DESC
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

SIN AGRUPAR OBTENGO LOS SIGUIENTES SET.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agrupando obtengo los siguientes set pero no me deja aplicar SUM() en la consulta SQL.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito ayuda con esto por favor. O una posible solución mediante variables utilizando SUM pero cómo agruparlo desde Jaspersoft?

Comment: Por favor tu consulta como texto, pues al momento como imagen es muy poco legible

Comment: @BetaM la pregunta ya fue editada. Gracias